# How to add an ID(selector) for the HTML tags using ng-class

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-class

I'm using an icon, which I display based on a condition using ng-class. I want to add ID's for both the HTML tags.

```
<i ng-show="ctrl.data.length > 1"
   ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': !ctrl.isOpen,
              'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up': ctrl.isOpen}">
</i>
```

Comment: Which tags are dynamic? How are they generated dynamically?

Comment: corrected my question - @lealceldeiro

Comment: And... what stops you? id="smth" ^^

Comment: This is too obvious as @PetrAveryanov said or... we're missing something here. Could you tell us why can't you set and id for your `<i>`. i.e.: `<i ng-show="ctrl.data.length > 1" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': !ctrl.isOpen, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up': ctrl.isOpen}" id="my-cool-id"></i>` ??

Comment: I'm trying to get one for chevron-down and one for chevron-up

Comment: Why you need different IDs depending on the rendered value of the ng-class? CSS aspect? Answer: you could use selectors like #yourid.chevron-down or #yourid.chevron-up. Logic aspect? Answer: Base your single ID related to your varibale ctrl.isOpen.

Comment: then you can id="{{ctrl.isOpen ? 'id1' : 'id2'}}"

Comment: Thanks that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a dynamic ID value, wrap it in `{{}}` so that Angular interprets that value.

```
<i ng-show="ctrl.data.length > 1" id="{{ctrl.isOpen ? 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down'}}"
   ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': !ctrl.isOpen,
          'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up': ctrl.isOpen}">
</i>
```